# Tomcat virtual host configuration

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost, tomcat5.5

**Background:**

I have a host configured in my Tomcat's server.xml as:

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" 
    appBase="webapps/myapp" 
    unpackWARs="true" 
    autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" 
    xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        <Context path="" docBase="."/>
    </Host>
```

**Problem:**

When I type `http://mydomain.com` into my browser, it works well. But when I type `http://www.mydomain.com` it shows a blank page.

**Workaround I tried:**

I tried to create another host as:

```
<Host name="www.mydomain.com" 
        appBase="webapps/myapp" 
        unpackWARs="true" 
        autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" 
        xmlNamespaceAware="false">
            <Context path="" docBase="."/>
        </Host>
```

**Result:**

It seemed to work okay ( when I typed `http://www.mydomain.com`, it would show me regular site ). But later I discovered this way Tomcat creates two instances of the same application; that invalidates this approach.

Please let me know if in your opinion there is a better workaround.

Many Thanks!

**P.S.**

This is my first question at serverfault.com, I am not sure if this question has been asked before ( at least I couldn't find any ). Link to any such related question would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a virtual host name alias.

```
<Host name="www.mydomain.com" ...>
  ...
  <Alias>mydomain.com</Alias>
  ...
</Host>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot XCondE, had no idea that it would be so simple :)